# hibernate default tuplizer

Tags: java, hibernate, tuplizer

I'm recieving an error:

```
Initial SessionFactory creation failed.org.hibernate.HibernateException: Unable to instantiate default tuplizer [org.hibernate.tuple.entity.EntityTuplizer].
```

I tried to change the tuplizer, but it did not help.

I already have javassist.jar in my classpath. 
Here is my mapping file:

```
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="vertical.model.filter.FilterOption" table="OPTION">
        <tuplizer entity-mode="dynamic-map" class="org.hibernate.tuple.entity.EntityTuplizer"/>
        <id name="id" type="long"/>
        <discriminator column="TYPE" type="string"/>
        <subclass name="vertical.impl.filter.options.AbstractFilterOption">
            <property name="name"/>
            <subclass name="vertical.impl.filter.options.Checkbox" discriminator-value="Checkbox">
                <property name="value" type="string"/>
            </subclass>
            <subclass name="vertical.impl.filter.options.Radio" discriminator-value="Radio">
                <property name="value" type="string"/>
            </subclass>
            <subclass name="vertical.impl.filter.options.CityInput" discriminator-value="CityInput">
                <property name="value" type="string"/>
            </subclass>
            <subclass name="vertical.impl.filter.options.Select" discriminator-value="Select">
                <property name="value" type="string"/>
            </subclass>
        </subclass>
    </class>
```

May it be some mistakes with mapping? I have a two-level inheritance here.

Comment: What hibernate version are you using? What is the root cause of this exception? Have you tried to set cglib instead of javaassist to be your bytecode instrumentation provider?

Comment: oh my god. I've look at the root of exception and understand that i forgot to add the setter method. Thank you!